# Spring.Net: Client referring to previous version of class

Tags: .net, spring.net

I'm trying to learn how to use Spring.Net by coding up a trivial example of one project calling another.

The project to be called is a class library project containing a single class and its corresponding interface:

```
public class ClassToBeConsumed : IClassToBeConsumed
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Ringo";
    }
}

public interface IClassToBeConsumed
{
    string GetName();
}
```

Now in a separate project I have a single console application. In this I am trying to use Spring.Net to form a coupling with the first project.

My single class in this project looks as follows:

```
namespace ClientApp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Get the context
        IApplicationContext applicationContext = ContextRegistry.GetContext();

        // Get the instance through Spring
        ClassToBeConsumed.IClassToBeConsumed _classToBeConsumed = (ClassToBeConsumed.IClassToBeConsumed) applicationContext["consumed"];

        string name= _classToBeConsumed.GetName();

        Console.WriteLine(name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

The config file is:

[image]

When I run the console app It outputs "Ringo". I then change the hard-coded name to "Paul" and compile the class library project. Now I run the console app again (without recompiling it. It still says "Ringo". If I recompile it it gives the expected answer however I thought that Spring.Net would update the code automatically without me having to do that.

Have I made a coding error or is my understanding of what Spring should be doing here incorrect?

Comment: Well, this has nothing to do with spring.net really. Have you copied the built .dll to the folder where the console app resides? If you had multiple classes implementing `IClassToBeConsumed`you could choose which one to resolve during runtime by changing the consoles app configuration.

Answer (score 0):

About old version of a specific class, it's not a spring.net issue or mistake. Generally environment issues can do that with your applications. Cleanup manually your bin, to understand if have any lock of any assembly (primarily the assembly that contains that class).

If your project was not marked for build, or references are not copied to your build/deployment folder.

Spring.Net does not have any behavior about assemblyes, with a container, that perform relations about instances, setting up all that configured, setting your dependencies, but never did anything about your assemblies.